# Firebase foreground push message has unreachable Notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-play-services

We have an extended `FirebaseMassageingService`:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        //todo
    }
}
```

When I receive a foreground push, in a debug I can see that it contains right notification content:
[image]

But the notification:

1. contains title = null, body = null
   [image]
   [image]
2. a push notification in the bar does not contain a title and a body and looks so:
   [image]

In our project, we have two different firebase projects one for debug and second for prod. So we have two different `google-services.json` files in debug and release build types.

Before we had started to use different projects everything was right and push notification contained a title and a body.

We (Android team) has no access to a Firebase console, projects were set-up without us, we just implement an Android "part".

**Qestion**

How to fix displaying of a title and a body in a push notification in a bar?
Is it our (Android) mistake or Firebase project settings issue or backend implementation?

Will appreciate any suggestion! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is backend implement issue. A few days ago I faced same issue. I think they are not using firebase server key to send push notification. It's work fine when app is in foreground.

Comment: @FarmanAliKhan thanks for the advice, but a back-end team says that they use server key, and I think that if they don't we will not receive push notifications at all, but we receive them.

Comment: If code is in PHP, then share code for sending push notification or I can give you code in core PHP.